# Can I Require a Recipient to Login Instead of Using an Access Code or Id Check?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

All of our system's users will have an account with DocuSign. However, our system will send automated signature requests that may or may not be sent by the signing user. These requests will include both customers and our users as recipients. Instead of protecting document access via an access code or id check, can I require our users to login to their DocuSign account?

I'm using the .NET DocuSign.eSign library available at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client.

Answer (score 2):

Signer Login Requirements can be set to login to a DocuSign account for each envelope access.

---

### In the console:

**Preferences** > **Features** > **Signer Login Requirements**
[image]

### In REST:

**PUT *{vx}*/accounts/*{accountid}*/settings**

```
{
    "accountSettings": [
        {
            "name": "signerMustHaveAccount",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "signerMustLoginToSign",
            "value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That seems like a global setting. I need some signers (customers) to just use an access code and other signers (employees) to login in to their DocuSign account, even when signing the same document. Will it work under those circumstances?